# Using service classes in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

So, I created `app/services` folder and then some classes inside with `.call` methods(I am trying to understand the logic of the services and query objects)

```
app/services/add_comment_to_post.rb

class AddCommentToPost
  def initialize(post:, comment:)
    @post = post
    @comment = comment
  end

  def call
    @post.comments.create(@comment)
    @post
  end
end


app/services/remove_comment_from_class.rb

class RemoveCommentFromPost
  def initialize(post:, comment:)
    @post = post
    @comment = comment
  end

  def call
    @post.comments.@comment.id.destroy
    @post
  end
end
```

and in the `comments_controller.rb`

```
     def create
        #this one works:
        #@post.comments.create! comment_params

        AddCommentToPost.new(@post, @comment).call
        redirect_to @post


     def destroy
         RemoveCommentFromPost.new(@post,@comment).call
         redirect_to @post
```

Can anybody tell me what should I change to make it works, or where to look for similar examples? The posts and comments are scaffolded, and I use nested routes.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

  root "posts#index"

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it's helpful if you include the error you're getting from what you've tried. In this case, I've scanned the code and noticed a couple of errors that you should correct.

Your service objects define their `initialize` method to take [keyword arguments](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments) like so:

```
def initialize(post:, comment:)
  @post = post
  @comment = comment
end
```

But you are initializing them by passing positional arguments like so:

```
AddCommentToPost.new(@post, @comment).call
```

You should initialize them with the expected keyword arguments like so:

```
AddCommentToPost.new(post: @post, comment: @comment).call
```

Additionally, as pasted above, your `destroy` method:

```
def destroy
  RemoveCommentFromPost.new(@post,@comment).call
  redirect_to @post
```

is missing an `end`.

Finally, you'll still want to check the return value of those service object calls to determine if the call succeeded or failed and handle appropriately. You are currently redirecting regardless.